# Reverse proxy Apache rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I've an apache reverse proxy and i try to make a rules for redirects few urls of example2 to example1 but my rewrite rules doesn't work.

I've try this in the vhost of example2 :

```
ProxyPass / https://example1.com/index2.html
ProxyPassMatch ^[A-Za-z0-9]$ https://example1.com/news-$1
```

The first rule work but not the second with ProxyPassMatch, when i go to https://example2.com/1test05 that return me a 404 Error but direct access to https://example1.com/news-1test05 work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you regex doesn't match.

`^[A-Za-z0-9]$` matches URIs composed of **one** alphanumeric character and you didn't put any leading slash nor capture group.

You need `ProxyPassMatch ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ https://example1.com/news-$1` instead.

Comment: You are right about the slash, but the line ProxyPass / https://example1.com/index2.html prevents the second rule to work properly, I need a rule to set a homepage without breaking the the second rule, I've test few rules with mod_proxy and mod_rewrite but I can't find the right rule.

Comment: @Olaf Swap both rules ? `^/[A-Za-z0-9]+$` doesn't match `/`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes I need a rule to set a homepage for https://example2.com/ pass through the proxy or not are no consequence for me maybe a DirectoryIndex index.html in vhost example2 work ? and I need a rule that redirects https://example2.com/1test05   to https://example1.com/news-1test05 and a rule that redirects https://example2.com/board/1test05 to https://example1.com/board/board-1test05

Comment: @Olaf You posted a question about a `ProxyPassMatch` rule not working, I answered. Now, you are trying to extend it to a complete different question and that's not how ServerFault works. One question, one issue. So things stay clear for readers and we don't get a whole bunch of comments below answers about things not related to the initial question. Ask another one if there's another thing you didn't mention that you can't manage to get working.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, i ask a new question but I'm not sure it's necessary because  the problem was my second rule doesn't work and now the second rule work but not the first rule because the two rules can't works together... so your solution is uncomplete.

Comment: @Olaf No it's not. You didn't swap both configuration lines as pointed out in the comments.